# Is it possible to generate native x86 code for ring0 in gcc?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, code-generation, native

I wonder, are there any ways to generate with the gcc some native x86 code (which can be booted without any OS)?

Comment: GCC always produces native x86 code...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth oh.. really? with ELF headers and some compression algorithms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question isn't well-formed.  Certainly not all of the instructions needed to initialize a modern CPU from scratch can be emitted by gcc alone, you'll need to use some assembly for that.  But that's sort of academic because modern CPUs don't actually document all this stuff and instead expect your hardware manufacturer to ship firmware to do it.  After firmware initialization, a modern PC leaves you either in an old-style 16 bit 8086 environment ("legacy" BIOS) or a fairly clean 32 or 64 bit (depending on your specific hardware platform) environment called "EFI Boot Services".

Operations in EFI mode are all done using C function pointers, and you can indeed build for this environment using gcc.  See the gummiboot boot loader for an excellent example of working with EFI.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the Linux kernel is compiled with GCC and runs in ring 0 on x86.